# Default locations for includes and libs

Tags: haskell, cabal, cabal-install

When using cabal-install to install a package you can use `--extra-include-dirs` and `--extra-lib-dirs` to use extra C header files and binaries (I might be wrong on that). However I'm not sure what the default locations are that cabal-install tries. Is it only the current directory or are there global default locations that are used as well?

Comment: Both `/usr/include` and `/usr/local/include` are certainly part of the default include dirs on Unix-like systems. (And similarly `/usr/lib` and `/usr/local/lib`.) 
My guess is that those are also the only directories that are there by default.

Comment: @mrueg: I'm actually on Windows at the moment, I should have mentioned that. Still knowing the locations of Unixes is useful, thanks.